# Why are the arguments of the following function being ignored?

Tags: javascript, regex

I created a function to replace strings in nested arrays recursively:

```
function replaceString(tree, oldStr, newStr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i])) {
      replaceString(tree[i])
    } else {
      tree[i] = tree[i].replace(oldStr, newStr)
    }
  }
}

function replaceQuotes(tree, callback) {
  var oldStr = /"(?=\b)/g
  var newStr = '“'

  replaceString(tree, oldStr, newStr)

  callback(null, tree) 
}
```

But for some reason the arguments are not being recognized, which is strange because if I do this:

`tree[i] = tree[i].replace(regex, str).replace(/"(?=\b)/g, '“')`

in the `findLastString` function, works perfectly fine.

What could be the problem?

This is the input:

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'para', '"a paragraph"' ],
  [ 'hr' ],
  [ 'para', '\'another paragraph\'' ],
  [ 'bulletlist',
    [ 'listitem', '"a list item"' ],
    [ 'listitem', '"another list item"' ] ] ]
```

Comment: Your code does not pass along the "oldStr" and "newStr" parameters when it makes a recursive call.

Comment: as an aside `\b` is a zero-width assertion, so it is useless to put it in a lookahead.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte I tried removing `\b`. If I do, it doesn't match anymore.

Comment: @alexchenco: you haven't understand, what you need to remove is not the `\b` but the lookahead!: `/"\b/`. An other thing, instead of `for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++)`, you can write: `for (var i  in tree)`

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Oh, I see. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try them out! So when should I use `for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++)`?

Comment: @alexchenco: only if you want garanted the order of keys of an object *(imagine an object like this: `{'2':'val2', '0':'val0', '1':'val1'}`)*, but in your case it is useless. However using `for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++)` is not an error at all. `for (var i in tree)` allows only to loop over all keys without to ask what is the array length and without to increment `i`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your recursive call, you are not passing the 2 arguments:

```
replaceString(tree[i])
```

should be:

```
replaceString(tree[i], oldStr, newStr)
```